# Advance Rolling mean (with conditions applying) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with one value and other string like this :

```
    Date        St  value   expected result
31/03/2015 0:03 Y   -108    -108
31/03/2015 0:08 Y   -108    -108
31/03/2015 0:13 Y   -108    -108
31/03/2015 0:18 Y   -108    -108
31/03/2015 0:23 Y   -108    -108
31/03/2015 0:28 N   -110    -108
31/03/2015 0:33 N   -111    -108
31/03/2015 0:38 Y   -123    -127
31/03/2015 0:43 Y   -129    -127
31/03/2015 0:48 Y   -129    -127
31/03/2015 0:53 Y   -129    -127
31/03/2015 0:58 N   -127    -127
31/03/2015 1:03 Y   -125    -125
31/03/2015 1:08 Y   -124    -125
31/03/2015 1:13 Y   -124    -125
31/03/2015 1:18 Y   -124    -125
31/03/2015 1:23 Y   -128    -125
31/03/2015 1:28 Y   -126    -125
31/03/2015 1:33 Y   -126    -125
31/03/2015 1:38 Y   -126    -125
31/03/2015 1:43 Y   -125    -125
31/03/2015 1:48 Y   -124    -125
31/03/2015 1:53 Y   -124    -125
31/03/2015 1:58 Y   -124    -125
31/03/2015 2:03 N   -124    -125
31/03/2015 2:08 N   -129    -125
31/03/2015 2:13 N   -130    -125
31/03/2015 2:18 Y   -130    -139
31/03/2015 2:23 Y   -130    -139
31/03/2015 2:28 Y   -133    -139
31/03/2015 2:33 Y   -140    -139
31/03/2015 2:38 Y   -140    -139
31/03/2015 2:43 Y   -145    -139
31/03/2015 2:48 Y   -145    -139
31/03/2015 2:53 Y   -147    -139
31/03/2015 2:58 N   -151    -139
31/03/2015 3:03 Y   -151    -168
31/03/2015 3:08 Y   -155    -168
31/03/2015 3:13 Y   -162    -168
31/03/2015 3:18 Y   -172    -168
31/03/2015 3:23 Y   -172    -168
31/03/2015 3:28 Y   -170    -168
31/03/2015 3:33 Y   -170    -168
31/03/2015 3:38 y   -170    -168
31/03/2015 3:43 Y   -177    -168
31/03/2015 3:48 Y   -177    -168
31/03/2015 3:53 Y   -177    -168
```

For this I would like to calculate the average of each of the chunk separetly with status 'Y' only, for example, I would like to calculate average of value from 31/03/2015 0:03 - 31/03/2015 0:23, similarly there would be other average value from 31/03/2015 0:38 - 31/03/2015 0:53. Is there any built in functionalities to handle this problem in pandas dataframe, I tried to use rolling mean function and grouping using 'Y' and 'N' but its not providing the solution what I want.

I tried like this :

```
status=my_data['St']=='Y'
mean_value=my_data.loc[status,'value'].mean()
```

Comment: Can we see expected output for given data and your try for getting the solution?

Comment: Thanks @Dark, I have added the expected result and what I tried..

Comment: I checked wether data was good compared to yours but you might have some rounding errors. The mean value from row `0:38` to `0:58` is -127.5 which should be 128 once rounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acording to the data you gave, this is how I would do it.

First of all, you need to [separate your `DataFrame` into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40204530/splitting-pandas-dataframe-into-many-chunks) and then forward fill the blanks in the `'N'` status column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# loading data
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %M:%S')
df = pd.read_csv('data.dat',delimiter='\s+', index_col=False,date_parser=dateparse, parse_dates={'datetime': ['Date', 'Time']})

# replacing labels by integers to ease comparison
replacedict = {'Y':1,'y':1,'n':0,'N':0}
df = df.replace(replacedict)
# separating in chunks 
lst = [g for _, g in df.groupby((df['St'].diff() != 0).cumsum())]
# Foward filling the blanks in the DataFrame
current_mean = None
for dff in lst:
    if (dff['St'] == 1).all():
        current_mean = dff['value'].mean()
    dff['actual_result'] = int(round(current_mean))
# building up finished DataFrame
new_df = pd.concat(lst)
```