# How to remove duplicate groups in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to remove duplicated sets in the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import pdb
filename = "result_4_tiling_116.csv"

chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, names=['id', 'tileID', 'x', 'y', 'h', 'w'], chunksize=chunksize):
    pdb.set_trace()
```

An example of the first 31 lines of the data:

```
chunk.head(31)

      tileID  x     y  h    w
0          0  0   0.0  1  8.0
1          1  0   8.0  1  8.0
2          0  0   8.0  1  8.0
3          1  0   0.0  1  4.0
4          2  0   4.0  1  4.0
5          0  0   0.0  1  4.0
6          1  0   4.0  1  4.0
7          2  0   8.0  1  4.0
8          3  0  12.0  1  4.0
9          0  0   4.0  1  4.0
10         1  0   8.0  1  4.0
11         2  0  12.0  1  4.0
12         3  0   0.0  1  2.0
13         4  0   2.0  1  2.0
14         0  0   8.0  1  4.0
15         1  0  12.0  1  4.0
16         2  0   0.0  1  2.0
17         3  0   2.0  1  2.0
18         4  0   4.0  1  2.0
19         5  0   6.0  1  2.0
20         0  0  12.0  1  4.0
21         1  0   0.0  1  2.0
22         2  0   2.0  1  2.0
23         3  0   4.0  1  2.0
24         4  0   6.0  1  2.0
25         0  0   8.0  1  4.0
26         1  0  12.0  1  4.0
27         2  0   0.0  1  2.0
28         3  0   2.0  1  2.0
29         4  0   4.0  1  2.0
30         5  0   6.0  1  2.0
```

I would like to filter out the duplicated ones. The data contains a set of groups (for each starting with tileID=0), as follows: 
1.

```
0          0  0   0.0  1  8.0
1          1  0   8.0  1  8.0
```

2.

```
2          0  0   8.0  1  8.0
3          1  0   0.0  1  4.0
4          2  0   4.0  1  4.0
```

3.

```
5          0  0   0.0  1  4.0
6          1  0   4.0  1  4.0
7          2  0   8.0  1  4.0
8          3  0  12.0  1  4.0
```

4.

```
9          0  0   4.0  1  4.0
10         1  0   8.0  1  4.0
11         2  0  12.0  1  4.0
12         3  0   0.0  1  2.0
13         4  0   2.0  1  2.0
```

5.

```
14         0  0   8.0  1  4.0
15         1  0  12.0  1  4.0
16         2  0   0.0  1  2.0
17         3  0   2.0  1  2.0
18         4  0   4.0  1  2.0
19         5  0   6.0  1  2.0
```

6.

```
20         0  0  12.0  1  4.0
21         1  0   0.0  1  2.0
22         2  0   2.0  1  2.0
23         3  0   4.0  1  2.0
24         4  0   6.0  1  2.0
```

7.

```
25         0  0   8.0  1  4.0
26         1  0  12.0  1  4.0
27         2  0   0.0  1  2.0
28         3  0   2.0  1  2.0
29         4  0   4.0  1  2.0
30         5  0   6.0  1  2.0
```

In this example, 5 and 7 are duplicated data. I try to use `drop_duplicates`, but no success yet.

Answer (score 1):

but look drop_duplicates is works

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"], "B":[0,1,1,1], "C":["A","A","B","A"]})
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'C'], keep=False)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be not the most efficient way to solve this problem, but it gives correct results.

Let `df` will be your initial dataframe:

```
unique_chunks = []
for _, chunk in df.groupby((df['tileID'].diff() != 1).cumsum()):
    unindexed_chunk = chunk.reset_index(drop=True)

    for unique_chunk in unique_chunks:
        unindexed_unique_chunk = unique_chunk.reset_index(drop=True)
        if unindexed_chunk.equals(unindexed_unique_chunk):
            break
    else:
        unique_chunks.append(chunk)

output_df = pd.concat(unique_chunks)
```

will give:

```
    tileID  x     y  h    w
0        0  0   0.0  1  8.0
1        1  0   8.0  1  8.0
2        0  0   8.0  1  8.0
3        1  0   0.0  1  4.0
4        2  0   4.0  1  4.0
5        0  0   0.0  1  4.0
6        1  0   4.0  1  4.0
7        2  0   8.0  1  4.0
8        3  0  12.0  1  4.0
9        0  0   4.0  1  4.0
10       1  0   8.0  1  4.0
11       2  0  12.0  1  4.0
12       3  0   0.0  1  2.0
13       4  0   2.0  1  2.0
14       0  0   8.0  1  4.0
15       1  0  12.0  1  4.0
16       2  0   0.0  1  2.0
17       3  0   2.0  1  2.0
18       4  0   4.0  1  2.0
19       5  0   6.0  1  2.0
20       0  0  12.0  1  4.0
21       1  0   0.0  1  2.0
22       2  0   2.0  1  2.0
23       3  0   4.0  1  2.0
24       4  0   6.0  1  2.0
```

The idea here is to iterate over the chunks of the initial dataframe, collect them in a list, and check the chunk on the current iteration if it is already present in that list. Don't forget to reset indices!

For explanations on how to iterate over chunks, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40204632/7851470).

---

**Edit:**
For the case of a very huge input file of ~20Gb you can try saving processed unique chunks to a file instead of keeping them in a list, and reading them back by chunks, in the same manner as you do it with your input file.

Comment: the data is huge, like 20GB. Not possible to read it as it is. I should use chunks